# Avoid client side code caching in angular

Tags: angular, hybrid, ng-upgrade

How to avoid caching of JavaScript, CSS, image files which are mentioned in Angular.JSON & in components. Basically we want to know how to handle caching or is there any way by which Angular handles it on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the `ng build` command. You should use `--output-hashing none`.

```
ng build --output-hashing media
```

This will only hash the media files, there are different options to use as per your needs. Check [this](https://angular.io/cli/build#options).

Comment: means media files will never be cached?

Comment: Yes, every time you create a new build or make changes to the medio file, it will change which is want you need.

Comment: Thanks for help, I am getting one more issue with media files, as media files get hashed, that files not getting loaded in app.

Comment: It should. Have you checked the hashed files in the build?